# Chaining in JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am going through a text book called Angular 2 Cookbook. In Chapter 4 there is a chaining Promises section which has the following code

```js
const incr = val => { console.log(val); return ++val;};

var outerResolve;

const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => { outerResolve = resolve;});

firstPromise.then(incr);

const secondPromise = firstPromise.then(incr);

const thirdPromise = secondPromise.then(incr);

outerResolve(0);
```

The output shown is

```
//0 0 0 1 1 2

//According to me output should be 0 0 1
```

Can someone please explain the result given in the book and the fault in my understanding of this vital concept?

Comment: There's nothing in this example that would be specific to Angular.

Comment: Well, test it, and see what happens. Books are sometimes wrong. This usage of outerResolve, instead of just resolving from inside the callback function passed to the promise constructor, also shows a lack of understanding of promises in the book.

Comment: ok I am testing it

Comment: So I am right the output is 0 0 1. Should I remove the question ?

Comment: That, or you can answer it, so that future readers wondering about this example in the book find your question and your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the book would correctly log as;

```
0
0
0
1
1
2
```

However you haven't analysed the example in full. The snippet that you provide in your question is just half of it. The example code in the book is as follows;

```js
const incr = val => { console.log(val); return ++val;};

var outerResolve;

const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => { outerResolve = resolve;});

firstPromise.then(incr);

const secondPromise = firstPromise.then(incr);

const thirdPromise = secondPromise.then(incr);

outerResolve(0);

secondPromise.then(incr);
firstPromise.then(incr);
thirdPromise.then(incr);
```

Comment: u are right apparently I made a mistake in seeing those three lines as comments (using kindle ebook). I will remove my question then I guess

Answer (score 1):

The output shown in the book's example is incorrect. 
The correct output is 0 0 1.

If the parent promise is resolved then it triggers the child promises to be resolved. So the following happens.

1. The firstPromise should be resolved and its handlers (2 in this case) should be called outputting 0 and 0 since the handlers are not chained.
2. Then secondPromise should be resolved and its handler should be called outputting 1.
3. Then thirdPromise should be resolved and as it has no handlers nothing will be outputted.